# Не работает всплывающая подсказка, сайт на WordPress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

Цель: всплывающая подсказка, которая ходит за мышкой.

Подскажите, почему такая конструкция не работает:

```
 <div class="et_pb_blurb_content">
                <div class="et_pb_main_blurb_image"><span class="et_pb_image_wrap"><img src="http://euroconveyor.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Проработка.png" alt="" class="et-waypoint et_pb_animation_top et-animated"></span></div>
                <div class="et_pb_blurb_container">
                    <h4 class="et_pb_module_header">Проработка</h4>
                    <div class="et_pb_blurb_description">
                        <h4>Проработка</h4><p>С самого начала к Вашему запросу прикрепляется технический специалист, который уточняет все нюансы чтобы сделать для Вас самое выгодное предложение</p>
                    </div><!-- .et_pb_blurb_description -->
                </div>
            </div>

 $(function() {
    $('.et_pb_blurb_description').hover(
      function(e) {
          $thisModal = $(this).children('.et_pb_blurb_description').show();
         });

      $('.et_pb_blurb_content').mousemove(function(e) {
          $(".et_pb_blurb_description").css('top', e.clientY + 10).css('left', e.clientX + 10);
        }
    );

    $('.et_pb_blurb').on('click', function(event) {
      $this = $(this);

      event.preventDefault();

    });

  });


    .et_pb_blurb_description
{
    background: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.40);
    color: #000000;
    display: none;
    font-size: 90%;
    padding: 30px 24px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    max-width: 492px;
    z-index: 10000;
}
.et_pb_blurb_description h4{
    color: #111111;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif, Helvetica, Arial;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
.et_pb_blurb_description p {
    color: #111111;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif, Helvetica, Arial;
    font-size: 0.8125rem;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: попробуй `function(e) { $thisModal = $(this).children('.et_pb_blurb_description').show(); }` заменить на `function(e) { $thisModal = $(this).show(); }`

Comment: Без изменений :(

Comment: а что в консоли браузера, есть ошибки?

Comment: Скорее всего, в консоли браузера ошибка `$ is not a function`. А все потому, что WordPress запускает jQuery в compatibility mode.

Comment: Я пока через jsfiddle пытаюсь запустить этот кусок кода. Как заработает, закину на сайт.

Comment: Это не показатель. Я объяснил, почему.

Comment: Т.е. с кодом всё в порядке?